# Smallest and Larest values of probability

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

The problem I was given is:

Suppose there are 60 students in a class including 30 CS majors and 20
Math minors (some students can be both CS majors and Math minors). Suppose there are two discussion sections and 40 students are in discussion section one and 20 are in discussion section two. If we pick a student at random, let D1 be the event they are in discussion section one and D2 be the event they are in discussion section two. Let C be the event that they are a CS major and let M be the event they are a Math minor.
P(D1 ∩ C) = P(D1)P(C) (i.e., D1 and C are indepent)

The question is:

What is the smallest value that P(D1|C) can take?

Here I am a bit confused as I'm not sure how much these values can vary.

approach 1:

I believe p(d1) is 2/3, as 40/60 students go to d1. p(c) seems to be 1/2, 30 out of 60 students.
p(d1|c) would them seem to be p(d1 n c) / p(c), with p(d1 n c) = 2/3 * 1/2 = 6/2. So it would be p(d1 n c) = 2/3. Not seeing how this would vary.

approach 2:

My other approach is to read it as given a computer science student, whats the smallest amount that could be in discussion 1, which would be 10, since a max of 20 could be in discussion 2. In which case the answer is 10.

Are either of those right, am I completely off track?

Answer (score 1):

If $D_1$ and $C$ are independent then $P(D_1|C)=P(D_1)=\frac{40}{60}$.  This is your first approach, though your calculations are unclear: I would prefer to see $P(D_1\cap C)= P(D_1)P( C)= \frac23 \times \frac12=\frac13$ .

Your second possible answer of $10$ is too big to be a probability. If you said $\frac{10}{30}$ as the minimum number of CS majors in discussion section one divided by the number of CS majors, this would ignore the independence.